# Cronbach Alpha for a test to be administered for two different samples

Tags: cronbachs-alpha

I need to calculate Cronbach's alpha for a test planned to be administered for two different samples. The test is planned to measure knowledge of these two samples, and these two samples vary on the level of knowledge on the topic which test measures. My question is: When finding cronbach alpha for such a test, **do I need to include test scores of people from both samples or only from one sample**? Or I have to find two cronbach alphas for both samples?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your situation. Could you post a small example dataset to illustrate it?

Answer (score 1):

Reliability (which alpha estimates) is a property of a test when applied to a population.

So it depends what you want to know, and what the samples are. If the two groups are males and females, I would probably combine them. If they were Americans and Germans, I would keep them separate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helps but still not clear if I should mix the participants of two groups to find one cronbach alpha or cronbach alphas for two groups separately ... I tried to explain in more details in my next question below :-)

Comment: It depends on what you want to know.

Comment: The samples are: a) students of psychology, b) students of political science. I found a study where they calculated cronbach alpha for each of two samples separately, then they tested the difference significance level between these two cronbach alphas using Fisher-Bonet Test. But, then they mention that they calculated Overall cronbach alpha, too. By overall do they mean they included two samples mixed for finding one cronbach alpha?

Comment: I guess they mean that they combined the two samples, yes.

Comment: If the way that the test will be used is in a mixture of both samples, then combine them.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it helped me a lot! :-). I would like to ask one more question, because its my first research for master thesis, I would appreciate if you could help me on this question, too: what should be the sample size for finding cronbach alpha for a 20 item questtionaire and 20 item multiple choice test? 10, 20, 40 participants or more in a sample? The total population is 200 persons. Thank you very much sir

Comment: There's little said about alpha and sample size, because you are not typically doing significance tests. More is better.